# Erro ao executar teste de integração continua - Travis-CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, travis-ci

Para fins de aprendizado estou utilizando o serviços do [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org) para realizar os teste de integração continua em um projeto pessoal. 
Ao executar o teste localmente todos passam, sem erros. Porém, ao serem executados no Travis-CI há este retorno.

https://travis-ci.org/luizpicolo/website-ruby-rspec-mongodb/builds/19042099

**Bem, o erro é bem claro, dizendo que não está encontrando os dados e por isso o retorno da erro.**

Para tanto, eu criei algums *Factories* para testar meus modelos. Elas são inseridas no banco durante o processo.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do 
    title "Title for Test"
    description ""
    body "Body for Test"
    position_image_highlighted "none"
  end

  factory :tag do
    name "Name for Test"
  end

  factory :slide do
    title   "Title for Test"
    link    "Link for test"
    image   "Image way for test"
  end
end
```

Contudo, e aparentemente, isso não acontece no Travis-CI. Alguém já passou por isso e pode dar uma solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de teres definido a factory, olhando [para o teu spec](https://github.com/luizpicolo/website-ruby-rspec-mongodb/blob/d70ab7ba7b496bacd1eaabf5031706ce6e389d34/spec/controllers/article_controller_spec.rb) parece-me que não estás a criar o objecto antes do teste.

Será possível que o teu teste falhou no TravisCI simplesmente porque os testes correram numa ordem diferente de quando correu localmente, dando por isso também um resultado diferente? É importante ter em conta que o rspec propositadamente corre os specs numa ordem aleatória, e os testes devem ser o mais atómicos e independentes possivel para evitar problemas com este aspecto.

Para criares o objecto, deves usar o método `let` para definires o artigo que vais aceder - podes ler mais sobre este método (e a variante `let!`) [aqui](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let).

Por exemplo:

```rb
describe ArticleController
  let(:article) { FactoryGirl.create(:article) }

  # ... código aqui ...
  get :show, :title => article.title
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Meu amigo perfeita resposta. Muito obrigado.